# I am trying to use the command hcitool and getting the error "Device is not available: No such device"

Tags: bluetooth, vmware

I am very new to using ubertoothOne and the VMWare virtual machine with Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS. I installed a virtual machine on my Windows laptop which has Bluetooth that I am able to connect to and works. I thought Bluetooth therefore would be available on my VM but I have the error: Connect a Bluetooth dongle. I say that because I am unsure if that is the reason that when I connect my UbertoothOne (I verified it is available by the command lsusb and it is there) I try to use the command hcitool dev and I get "Device is not available: No such device". I have tried **hcitool -i hci2 scan** to see if by changing the hci port I may get something, to no avail. Please is there a solution?

I am using an HP laptop and Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS on the VM I installed.
I have an UbertoothOne device and I am using it for various other scans

Comment: It *may* be possible to share the host's bluetooth device, but there are steps required. See for example [Sharing Bluetooth devices with a virtual machine](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2005315). Regardless, this is really a question about vmware / virtualization rather than about Ubuntu

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out. I needed a Bluetooth dongle attached as well contrary to what I supposed thinking I had inbuilt installed Bluetooth in the computer